# Nested ternery conditional not woring in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am trying to have a nested ternary conditional in a `useEffect` hook in ReactJS.
I have done this before with no problem outside of a useEffect hook, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

My working code looks like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (myState != '') {
      checkbox ? (
        trueFunction()
      ) : (
        falseFunction
        )
    }
  }, [x]);
```

This works as expected.
When i try to do this with ternary operators it doesn't execute any of my functions inside.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    myState != '' ?? (
      checkbox ? (
        trueFunction()
      ) : (
        falseFunction
        )
    )
  }, [x]);
```

Comment: you are using Nullish coalescing `??` instead of a ternary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `myState != ''` will always return either `true` or `false`, you are using the *Nullish coalescing operator (??)* inappropriate, take a look at the documentation => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 1):

Either this

```
useEffect(() => {
    myState != '' && (
      checkbox ? trueFunction() : falseFunction()
    )
  }, [x]);
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
    myState != '' ? (
      checkbox ? trueFunction() : falseFunction()
    ) : null
  }, [x]);
```